# Enabling allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox in IFRAME mode

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a Google Sheets Add-On that creates PDF (on an external server).

Our current Add-On is based on the now deprecated ui interface.

We would like to switch to IFRAME mode.

One problem is, that IFRAME mode disables PDF display in secondary windows (created form the sidebar) on Google Chrome (it allows them with Firefox).

The other problem is, that the user is not able to print from secondary windows on Chrome. (This prevents us from using pdf.js for PDF display, because printing is still impossible).

Is there a chance to enable allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox in IFRAME mode.

This would atleast solve our problems for Google Chrome on Windows (not on Mac).

Comment: You might want to ask this question in the following Google Group.  [Developing add-ons for Google Docs/Sheets/Forms](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: I already did (together with the Stackoverflow post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe developers cannot set sandbox flags. This is set by Google. Good news is that starting today (September 16, 2015) I noticed that the flag `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` is being added to the `HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME`

When my add-on opens up the desktop chrome browser is throwing an error `Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox' is an invalid sandbox flag.` right now. I have the latest stable version `Version 45.0.2454.93 m`

This error should go away with [release 46](https://www.chromestatus.com/features) as per the documentation I can see online. If you wanted you could download the beta version (46) or dev version (47) to test it out. I wouldn't recommend deploying beta/dev for anything other than testing/development. Please note the compatibility risk with other browsers.